# How to turn a Graphics primitive into a list of data?

Tags: image-processing, discretization

I tried something small first, to get a feeling about this. So I defined a `Rectangle[]`, placed it in a corner of `Graphics[PlotRange->{...}]` and defined an `ImageSize`. After applying `Binarize[]` and `ImageData[]` consecutively, I got an array of data. Perfect so far, but:

1. The dimension of the data does not equal the dimensions of `ImageSize[]`, why?
2. Why aren't the rows filled with 0 directly positioned at the edge, as the `Rectangle[]` is supposed to be positioned in the corner?

My example:

```
periode = 10;
length = 5;
height = 2;

rect = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, height}];

gr = Graphics[rect, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, periode}, {0, periode}}, 
  ImageSize -> {periode, periode}]

data = ImageData[Binarize[gr]]
Dimensions[data]
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It seems like there is a minimal size gr has to have. In my laptop (MMA v10) Dimensions[data] is always {17,periode} for every periode<13. Setting periode greater than 12 results in a rectangle on the lower left side but with false dimensions. Is 17 perhaps my 'standard line' height in pixels? In your case it would be 16 and in Dr. belisarius (counting the pixels in the image provided) about 9.

Comment: Do you see `BoxMatrix` or I misunderstand your purpose?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `BoxMatrix`. However, for arbitrary shaped graphics, which I have in mind (e.g. ring, star, whatever) the command won't be useful, wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this regular we know the min height of `Graphics` is 16

```
(Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> {1, #}] // Binarize // 
     ImageData // Dimensions) & /@ Range@19
```

> {{16, 1}, {16, 1}, {16, 1}, {16, 1}, {16, 1}, {16, 1}, {16, 1}, {16,1}, {16, 1}, {16, 1}, {16, 1}, {16, 1}, {16, 1}, {16, 1}, {16,1},{17, 1}, {17, 1}, {18, 1}, {19, 1}}

So we make this function like following

```
getmat[width_, height_] := 
 Module[{pic}, 
  pic = Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {width, height}]}, 
     ImageSize -> {width, height}] // Binarize;
  If[height <= 16, ImageData@ImageResize[pic, {width, height}], 
   ImageData@pic]]
```

Usage:

```
getmat[15, 6] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Also as the concise you can like this

```
getmat[width_, height_] :=ImageData@ImageResize[
   Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {width, height}]}, 
     ImageSize -> {width, height}] // Binarize, {width, height}]
```

Then `getmat[15, 6] // MatrixForm` will get same result.

Comment: Interesting, it never came to my mind to think of something like a lower limit for `ImageSize`. Your answer is greatly helpful, as it solves both of my above questions. Thank you!